# How to keep uses list of several projects identical

Tags: delphi, testing

I have a client application and a test application. If someone adds/removes units to the client application, I would like the same changes to happen to the test application.

I can think of 3 ways to do it, but all have drawbacks

**1. Manually update the Test project uses list in the dpr.**

The problem here is obvious, requires manual intervention per project.

**2. Use a shared .inc file that contains the list of used units (list of frmXXX in '\forms\frmXXX.pas'...)**

IDE doesn't like .inc files in the project file and would again require manual work to maintain

**3. Same as #2, but use a shared unit instead of .inc file. So instead of updating the .inc you update the shared .pas**

IDE would not really consider the files used by a shared unit as files in the project and they wouldn't get listed in View Unit dialog

---

Are there any other ways to keep uses lists of multiple projects in sync that I'm missing ?

Currently using D2007 but hopefully that doesn't matter.

Comment: Another solution is to put the units in a package that is referenced by the various projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a build tool like Apache Ant, maintain the unit names in the script file (or a configuration file), and let Ant replace a placeholder in all *.dpr files using the [replace task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html).

This would regenerate the dpr file automatically and keep them in sync.

Comment: Actually, we already use FinalBuilder and you gave me an idea. We could write a small tool that compares the dpr files, merges changes and then if any changes are needed, checks out&in the file.
Run this in the FB script before it builds the TestProject